# How do I use a Service to consume Location data?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-location, android-intentservice

Since I have a long-running task to perform in the background of my app, I'm trying to implement a Service to do a job.

This Service uses location data from a [LocationClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) instance and each request is fired with a PendingIntent. Minimum target version prevents me from using the new LocationServices and Android documentation advised me to use the PendingIntent version of the LocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(...) method, because the [application may have been killed by the system](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

[Every](http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html#HandleUpdates) [example](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) [I've](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2757337) seen which matches a similar description implements an IntentService and overrides onHandleIntent(Intent intent) which receives intents KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED extra. However, there is no such method in Service and such intents are not delivered to onStartCommand(...) as I would have expected.

This code is used to set up a request for location data and comes from a LocationRequester object (there could be any number of these running at any one time, but the result is the same when just one is spawned and makes the request):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyLocationService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(someLocationRequest, pendingIntent);
```

When I used MyLocation*Intent*Service in the above code, Intents would be delivered to MyLocationIntentService.onHandleIntent(intent), and I would look for the KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED extra. After making the change to a Service, I do not know how to consume the location data. I have made sure that the LocationClient is connected when the request is made.

I've tried monitoring onStartCommand(...) and the intents do not get delivered there. My question is: How do I consume location data in a Service implementation?

If I've left anything unclear or more information is needed, please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found myself a solution, though it's not quite as clean as I would like.

I used the Service to create Requester objects, which were each implementations of LocationListener and consumed only their own requests. This meant abandoning a couple of constraints in the question :(. The Requester object would, upon receiving a location (in the overwritten onLocationChanged(...) method, fire off an intent to the service with the specific details as Extras.

In other words, the Service didn't directly consume location data - the individual that requested it did, and forwarded it back to the Service by making an Intent, attaching the relevant data and calling startService(...), which was picked up by Service.onStartCommand(...).